# Using Linq to group hourly and get an hourly average

Tags: c#, linq, highcharts

I cannot seem to work out how to do this.
I have an object that has a `DateTime` property and an `int`

I want to group the `DateTime` hourly and then have the `TimeTaken` property averaged per hour.

**Model**

```
public class ChartModel
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int TimeTaken { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult PopulateResponseTimeChart()
{
    // selectedItem is a type of IEnumerable<ChartModel>
    var average = selectedItem.GroupBy(x => x.Date.Date).Select(x => new { Date = x.Key, Average = x.Average(a => a.TimeTaken) });
    var data = average.Select(x => x.Average.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture)).ToArray();
    var time = average.Select(x => x.Date).ToArray();

     // Other stuff
 }
```

This above doesn't seem to work. `average` only contains 1 result, when i'm expecting it to be hourly.
The reason behind this is I want to use it in the JS libary Highcharts

Comment: How would you expect it to be hourly? You haven't got anything which specifies an hourly grouping or anything similar in your code. You're grouping by date, and then for each date you're creating a single record which has the date and the average time taken for all records on that day.

Comment: Correct, I am not sure how to do this, this is my question. I will edit my OP to make sure it's clear what I am asking.

Comment: So is it just a matter of grouping by date *and* hour of day? There are various ways to achieve that, including `...GroupBy(x => new { x.Date.Date, x.Date.Hour })`

Comment: It's also I need `TimeTaken` to be an average per grouped hour?

Comment: Well that's okay because you're averaging *on the group*.

Comment: Thanks guys! Got it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
selectedItems.GroupBy(x => x.Date.Hour)
             .Select(g => new { Hour = g.Key, AverageTimeTaken = g.Average(x => x.TimeTaken) });
```